# Dagger 1.2.2 downgrade to Dagger 1.2.0 for Google Auto Factory

Tags: java, android, guice, dagger

Does anyone know of any side effects of doing this?

I'm going to attempt to downgrade to use Google Auto (https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory) since there are a lot of reports of 1.2.1 / 1.2.2 being incompatible.

Of course I'm going to try to see if I can just drop Google Auto Factory in from the get go to see what happens, but looking to see if the project maintainer(s) plan on any update or fix in the near future for these libraries.

Comment: Where are these reports? What have you tried 1.2.2?

Comment: https://github.com/google/auto/issues/76 someone had a problem. I am trying to integrate at the moment to test it out. Will report results.